# WindowsForms - C# - ReportViewer - Objeto composto

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

Boa tarde,

Estou começando a desenvolver relatórios usando o ReportViewer para aplicações Desktop usando WindowsForms (C#).

Estou com problemas para objetos compostos por outros, exemplo:

```
class Produto
{
   public int Codigo { get; set; } 
   public string Nome { get; set; }
   public Grupo Grupo { get; set; }
}

class Grupo
{
   public int Codigo { get; set; } 
   public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Minha fonte de dados para o relatório é um List de Produtos, a List do objeto produto com seus respectivos grupos estão preenchidos, mas recebo **#Error** ao tentar colocar o Grupo (que num datagridview ficaria Gsis.Model.Grupo) ou quando tento uma expressão do tipo =Fields!Grupo.Value.Descricao

O que estou dizendo pode ser melhor entendido na imagem abaixo:
[image: Erro no relatório em ReportViewer]

Estou usando o Visual Studio Community 2015 no Windows 10.

Grato pela ajuda,

Marcos Gerene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de um tempo consegui fazer isso com Report Viewer, segue exemplo completo.

A classe `Produto` e `Grupo`(Categoria) precisam ter o seguinte atributo: `[Serializable]`

```
[Serializable]
public class Produto
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Categoria
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

As formulas no ReportViewer podem ser de duas formas:

Fórmula para exibir apenas um registro:

```
=First(Fields!Categoria.Value.Nome, "DataSetProdutos")
```

Fórmula para exibir vários registros no objeto table:

```
=Fields!Categoria.Value.Nome
```

Para passar os dados para o relatório:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        var produtos = new List<Produto>
        {
            new Produto { Codigo = 1, Nome = "Produto 1" , Preco = 20, Categoria = new Categoria { Codigo = 1, Nome = "Categoria 1"} },
            new Produto { Codigo = 1, Nome = "Produto 2" , Preco = 30, Categoria = new Categoria { Codigo = 2, Nome = "Categoria 2"} }
        };

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSetProdutos", produtos));
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
  }
```

No link que peguei por referência é sugerido a criação de um construtor sem parâmetros, mas funcionou sem o mesmo normalmente.

Print mostrando que funcionou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referências

http://wraithnath.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/reportviewer-object-datasource-nested.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577425/visual-studio-2013-rdlc-how-to-display-values-from-navigation-properties